# Create TUN and Routing In Windows 7

Tags: windows, vpn, tun

I am playing around with an application to do some remote connection and I am struggling with understanding the tun/tap.  I have installed OpenVPN tuntap driver and can connect/configure it through my application but I need some clarification.

If I use it in TAP mode I need to bridge my network adapters correct??

How would a TUN interface be setup?? I know that I need to call `DeviceIoControl` with `TAP_IOCTL_CONFIG_TUN` and I think I understand how but my research leads me to think I also need to add into the windows routing tables??

Can someone layout what a typical TUN Layer3 VPN would look like

Thanks
Matt